# Acentuação em pdf para a biblioteca HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html

Eu estou gerando um PDF só que preciso que a biblioteca permita a utilização de acentuação ?
Alguém tem uma idéia de como fazer isso no HTML2PDF?
Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O HTML2PDF utiliza o enconde `latin1_swedish_ci` para gerar os seus pdf.
para corrigir isso basta você definir setar como `utf8_encode()` ou `iconv()` e gerar novamente.

Para mais informações sobre utf8_encode
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php

---

ou experimente adicionar utf-8 inline

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'pt');
```

Ficaria assim:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'pt', true, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Obrigado Thallyson valeu mesmo! Funfou!